# Migrated repo to Git LFS, clones much slower now

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

Our repo was migrated from svn to git a year ago, hosting on our company's Gitlab server. We were new to git so weren't aware of the issues with adding binary files, of which our svn repo contained a lot (which frequently changed).

This past week I migrated the repo to use git lfs following this guide: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#migrating-existing-repository-data-to-lfs

It worked great for me and most developers on my team. Unfortunately, two of the developers are having an issue with their clone operation takes hours (versus minutes for the rest of us). This is worse than pre-migration to LFS.

The big difference I can see from their clone is this:

For those without issue, our clone's last step is "Filtering content".

However, for the two with this issue, their console prints out "Downloading ..." every single binary file. This step takes forever as it iterates over every single binary file, downloading them one by one.

I don't see anything that stands out in their git config that could cause this. Just wondering if anyone has encountered an issue with clones taking forever after migration to git lfs. I tried googling but couldn't find anyone with this issue.

Comment: are you only storing the binary files in the lfs? or all the files?

Comment: @DanielA.White Just the binary files.

Comment: The LFS wrapper software puts the large files on a separate server (not the Git server). If they have a fast connection to the Git server and a slow connection to the LFS server, this would happen. If that's not it, it's possible that they're using an ancient version of LFS that is relatively stupid and slow (and work with old Git versions), vs the modern ones that are clever and fast (and require newer Gits). Nothing in their *Git* config will have anything to do with this, it's all in the *LFS adapters*. Check the git-lfs version and the Git version, and their LFS configuration for Git.